# Handling forall inside an hypothesis

Tags: coq, isabelle

I have just finished my PhD in CS. Now, I am currently learning coq. I am following the course of [Software Foundations](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/current/lf-current/)), which is really good and I am learning a lot. I am starting also a little project to use all of the methods that I have learned.

I am stuck in the following situation:
`Lemma aux (x : nat) : (forall i : nat, True -> i <= x) -> False.`

It should be really easy to prove it, but I am not able to handle the forall inside the hypothesis. I think it should be enough just by saying that i = (x+1), and then we get, x+1 <= x, which is false. But I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate the hypothesis `H : forall i : nat, True -> i <= x` with `S x` (which is a simpler way of writing `x+1`) using the `specialize` tactic:

```
(* Goal:
...
H : forall i, True -> i <= x
----------------------------
False
*) 

specialize (H (S x)).

(* or, to also get 'True' out of the way: *)
specialize (H (S x) I).
```

Alternatively, a little more long-winded solution but using more basic tactics: use `assert` to claim the specialized proposition, and prove it using `apply`:

```
intros H.  (* H : forall i, True -> i <= x *)
assert (contra : S x <= x).
{ apply H. auto. }

(* Goal:
...
contra : S x <= x
--------------------
False
 *)
```

Comment: Thank you. The proof was quite bigger than that, but thanks to your suggestion I have been able to prove it all. Thank you so much!